# Forms Authentication working on IE, but not on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, web

I have the following code to authorise a user

```
bool isValidUser = AccountService.IsValidUser(username, password, out message);
        if (isValidUser)
        {
            var user = new UserDTO {Username = username, Password = password};
            SetAuthCookie(username, true, user);
            Response.Redirect(App_GlobalResources.Urls.Position, true);
        }
       protected void SetAuthCookie(string name, bool rememberMe, IUserDTO userData)
        {
            // In order to pickup the settings from config, we create a default cookie and use its values to create a  new one.
            var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(name, rememberMe);
            var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
            var userJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userData);
            var newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration,
                ticket.IsPersistent, userJson, ticket.CookiePath);
            var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
            // Use existing cookie. Could create new one but would have to copy settings over...
            cookie.Value = encTicket;
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
```

And this is how my `web.config` looks like

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Pages/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="120" slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>
<machinekey decryptionkey="mydescriptionkey,IsolateApps" validationkey="validationKey,IsolateApps" />
```

When I use the app on IE the `.ASPXAUTH` cookie is created. However, this is not happening on `Chrome` or `Firefox`. I have just **updated** the framework of the project from `4` to `4.5.2`. I don't know if this may be causing this because the app used to work on these browsers.

Comment: Are you sure of that ? Because there is no browser dependencies in .Net code so it is very strange to havec this king of scenario. Do you have cookies enabled on Chrome or Firefox ?

Comment: I'm not saying that changing the framework must be the reason, I'm just listing one of the last changes I did before it stopped working.

Cookies are working in other sites like Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok I'm not saying you change the framework ^^. Just try to understand the environment. Have you tried to remove some part of code and see when that works again ?

Comment: I don't know exactly what other changes could have triggered it. Another developer has it working fine on his google chrome browser, so I think it may be more related to my browser configuration.

Comment: Do you have any administration restrictions applied by your SI Team could explain this issue on your workstation ?